# Android Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so

Tags: android, dex

I got this crash reported on the play developer console from a Galaxy S4.  Any clue what it's about?

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/jfltespr/jfltespr:5.0.1/LRX22C/L720VPUGOK3:user/release-keys'
Revision: '11'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 19535, tid: 19535, name: >>> com.company.package <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'sart/runtime/class_linker.cc:3054] Check failed: dex_cache.Get() != nullptr Failed to allocate dex cache for /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk'
    r0 00000000  r1 00004c4f  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
    r4 b6f4e114  r5 00000006  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c
    r8 00000001  r9 b4f4f520  sl b4f07800  fp b3b6db00
    ip 00004c4f  sp beceff10  lr b6ed7fd1  pc b6efaeb4  cpsr 60070010

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00036eb4  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 00013fcd  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
    #02 pc 00014beb  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 00011531  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
    #04 pc 0000fcbc  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 0021d9d9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+160)
    #06 pc 000a8363  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1322)
    #07 pc 000ce557  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::RegisterDexFile(art::DexFile const&)+330)
    #08 pc 000d37e5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::FindClassInPathClassLoader(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable&, art::Thread*, char const*, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>)+424)
    #09 pc 000d3af9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE.part.403+356)
    #10 pc 000d65e3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::ResolveType(art::DexFile const&, unsigned short, art::Handle<art::mirror::DexCache>, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>)+122)
    #11 pc 000d685d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::ResolveMethodExceptionHandlerTypes(art::DexFile const&, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+316)
    #12 pc 000d6953  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::ResolveClassExceptionHandlerTypes(art::DexFile const&, art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>)+46)
    #13 pc 000d6b8f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::VerifyClass(art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>)+470)
    #14 pc 000d81bf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::InitializeClass(art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>, bool, bool)+270)
    #15 pc 000d8c13  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::EnsureInitialized(art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>, bool, bool)+54)
    #16 pc 00288037  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickResolutionTrampoline+598)
    #17 pc 000a424b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_resolution_trampoline+10)
    #18 pc 0010fa7c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (deleted)
```

Here's the primary error message pulled out from that mess:

`Abort message: 'sart/runtime/class_linker.cc:3054] Check failed: dex_cache.Get() != nullptr Failed to allocate dex cache for /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk'`

There were no user comments so I have no idea how to reproduce it.  Is there anything I can do to track this down?

Comment: If a crash report doesn't show any of your own code, there is a good chance it's not your fault and it's a problem on the consumer device. I would ignore it.

Comment: Looks like it could be an out-of-memory type of error

Comment: @DougStevenson Not true at all.  It isn't uncommon for the android framework to crash in native code and leave a stack like this, caused by something you did in Java

Comment: @GabeSechan But a crash in your native code it would still show YOUR .so here. This particular trace is entirely filled with platform objects.

Comment: @DougStevenson  No it doesn't.  I'd say it does that about 10% of the time.  Dieing in libc.so with no reference to your code for memory errors due to you misinitializing stuff is common, for example.

Comment: I have had memory issues on these apps before so that is a possibility.

Comment: This particular issue is a known problem with the ART runtime on certain early 5.0 Samsung phones.

Comment: @GabeSechan Got any links to further info?  And thanks.

Comment: Now I'm curious to see an actual native dump like this that doesn't show the app's objects anywhere but it still the fault of the app's code.

Comment: @nasch Trying to hunt it down.  I know we saw it at my last employer, but I don't know what we did to mitigate it (and I don't think we ever completely solved it, but we got it down to an occassional problem rather than a constant one)

Comment: According to the diff https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/a436fde%5E!/   this is caused if you run out of memory while trying to load a new class for the first time.  So its an OOM issue, just hitting you at an unusual point leading to this stack trace.

Comment: So sounds like it's an OOME but I won't be able to get any information about where or why it happened unless I can reproduce it, does that sound about right?